# What is typical architecture of a Reverse Proxy?

Tags: c++, plugins, webserver, weblogic, reverse-proxy

I tried scouring the net and 90% of times came across pages detailing "HOW" to use Apache to implement the reverse proxy.

I am thinking how exactly the reverse proxy plugins is coded?

1. I know they parse the request and see to which server it should be routed to.
2. Do they then create a thread for every connection from the end user and then delegate that thread the responsibility to connect to right server.
3. Keep on accepting more requests from other clients and creating similar threads.
4. When thread gets the response from server, reply with that to the client. And close the thread. Or do they have a thread pool?

I am thinking about it from C++ angle. If multithreading is used to increase the proxy's throughput.

Comment: There are several open source proxies available, I think the best thing to do is to study their sources.  [Pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound) is a relatively compact standalone reverse proxy and maybe a good starting point?

Comment: Many thanks. Going through it now.

Answer (score 3):

A bit dated, but very much worth the read - http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html.  After reading that you should have a good idea of why a thread per connection is a really bad idea.  If you are really interesting in learning how scalable or high performance servers are implemented, I suggest digging in and reading some source code.  I particularly like the source for Apache HTTPD.